# RxJS: Programmable Timer

Tags: javascript, timer, rxjs

I am trying to insert a variable time delay between array elements using Observables. In this example I want to move a rabbit icon horizontally on the screen. Like a water gun race at an arcade. Here is my input array

```
    var inputArray = [
       {locationX: 100, timeDelay: 2000},
       {locationX: 500, timeDelay: 8000},
       {locationX: 700, timeDelay: 3000}
    ]
```

In this example the rabbit would move to location 100px after 2 seconds, then to location 500px after an 8 second delay, etc....

```
    var obs = Rx.Observable.from(inputArray)
        .flatMap( x => return Rx.Observable.timer(x.timeDelay) )
```

The above code does not work. I just loops thru the array without a time delay. Any ideas?

Comment: Mmm... I do not see the error, this is working for me http://jsbin.com/wogeposefa/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thanks Miguel for your code sample. It was the return that caused my code to fail. I now have another question... How would I send x.locationX back to the subscriber?

Comment: .flatMap( x => Rx.Observable.timer(x.timeDelay).map(() => x.locationX )

Comment: @MartyB you have now the answer for both questions now.

Comment: Thank You Meir (and Miguel) That worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here it's a working example, you have to eliminate the `return` statement, and add a result selector [function] to flatMap, it will iterate over each element and pass it to your subscribe. Here you have the working example http://jsbin.com/jutizataji/edit?js,console,output

```js
var inputArray = [
       {locationX: 100, timeDelay: 500},
       {locationX: 500, timeDelay: 1000},
       {locationX: 700, timeDelay: 5000}
    ]

Rx.Observable
  .from(inputArray)
  .flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.timer(x.timeDelay), (x) => x)

  // here x represent each object inside your input array, to access location do x.locationX
  .subscribe((x) => { console.log(x); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. flatMap will execute for each emission as soon as its available (`.merge` behaviour). Using `.concatMap` it will process the current emission before starting on the next:

```js
    var inputArray = [
           {locationX: 100, timeDelay: 500},
           {locationX: 500, timeDelay: 1000},
           {locationX: 700, timeDelay: 5000}
        ]
    
    Rx.Observable
      .from(inputArray)
      .concatMap(i => Rx.Observable.just(i).delay(i.timeDelay))
      .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

It's best not to have `n` timers running as per the answer of Miguel Lattuada because that might give you memory issues.

Comment: Mark, thanks for pointing that out. To explain, lets say the the inputArray timeDelays were reversed, say [...5000,...1000,...500] With flatMap the third element would be executed first. Not what I wanted! concatMap fixed that by keeping the inputs in the original order.